# Abrir documento php en localhost desde Sublime Text

Tags: php, sublimetext3, wamp

Tengo un problema, nunca he usado Sublime Text y me gustaría que al editar un fichero php, al pulsar por ejemplo la tecla f12 desde sublime se abriese en localhost (Chrome). Pero no consigo hacerlo.

Tengo el wanpserver activo y la dirección de mi proyecto es:

http://localhost.prueba/

He instalado el plugin View in browser y logro abrir el archivo con Chsome, pero lo hace desde una ruta relativa y no desde mi servidor php con localhost.

Según parece hay que configurar las rutas de mi proyecto. He leído por varios sitios que se hace en **Project -> Edit Project URLs** pero en el menú Project no aparece esa opción.

[image: Captura de las opciones de Sublime]

Por favor, a ver si estoy haciendo algo mal, he instalado Sublime Text 64. ¿Por qué no aparece esa opción? ¿me he saltado algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aconsejo una solución alternativa a su duda, desde mi punto de vista, mucho mas práctica/útil y es que yo utilizo sublime text desde hace 2 años y creo que todavía no he necesitado algo que no pueda usar o conseguir en sublime.

Por ello, en todo lo referente a desarrollo sobre navegador recomiendo utilizar LiveReload. 
 
http://livereload.com/

¿Porqué?

Bueno, es un `plugin/addon/libreria` de Sublime Text. Su objetivo es refrescar el navegador cada vez que realizas la acción de guardar sobre tu proyecto.
Digamos que sincroniza sublime text con tu navegador en `Firefox, Chrome y Safari`, es decír, para los sistemas operativos mas comunes en el desarrollo/programación sobre navegador.

Cada vez que guardas tu proyecto, este se actualiza en el navegador, hace un, simple refresh. Por cierto, mencionar que las cookies del navegador pueden hacer que no haga el refresh correcto como es logico, parece algo logico/tonto lo que digo pero cuando llevas años usando esto...te acostumbras tanto que ya casi es "obligatorio" que cada vez que guardas sublime..¡DEBE! reflejarse....y a veces si se olvida quitar las cookies, puedes pasarlo mal. "True story"

Mi solución definitiva fue trabajar en MODO INCOGNITO.
Si, también puedes utilizarlo en modo incógnito, no podia estar mejor el LiveReload =).

¿Cómo instalarlo?

1-Primero tener instalado Sublime Text
2-Instalar Package Controll
El Package Control es una libreria de Sublime text que te permite gestionar los paquetes u otros plugin/adons sobre sublime text. 
Esto nos va a `permitir instalar libreria de LIVERELOAD` sobre Sublime text.

Instalar el Package control es extremadamente sencillo:
2.a) En sublime text, arriba vas a  `views > show console` (Se abre consola)
2.b) En la consola de sublime text pegas el texto copiado de esta web.
*Tanto para sublimetext2 como para el SBT3, elige el que tengas.
https://packagecontrol.io/installation
2.c) Reinicia el sublime text cuando hagas instalaciones para que tengan efecto correcto y evitar fallos.

3) Ahora `INSTALAR LiveReload` SOBRE Sublime Text
3.a) Inicamos nuevamente Sublime Text
3.b) Comando `Ctrl + Shift + P`, se abre una ventanita en forma de `INPUT`.
3.b) Arriba escribes `install pack` y deberia ser suficiente para ver `Package Control: Install Package`, que es el gestor instalador de paquetes para sublime.
Te desplazas con las felchas y pulsas intro.
3.c) Al seleccionarlo (Necesitas conexión a internet), aparece una lista que son todos los paquetes que puedes instalar en sublime text. 
3.d) Debemos buscar `LiveReload plugin` y pulsas intro sobre ese concretamente.
 En la parte inferior izquierda del editor de texto Sublime Text podrás ver el progreso de la instalación. 
3.e) Una vez finalizado e instalado, reiniciar sublime text de nuevo.

4) Ahora `Configurar LiveReload de Sublime`
4.a) Accedes a `Preferences > Package settings > LiveReload > settings-Default`
4.b) En el archivo `LiveReload.sublime-settings`, debes tener el siguiente codigo, añade todo o lo que te falte: 
`{
    "enabled_plugins":[
        "Refresh",
        "SimpleReloadPlugin",
        "SimpleRefresh"
    ]
}`

5) Hasta aquí hemos terminado con sublime text. Ahora queda el navegador.

5.a) Busca Livereload + "Tu navegador" (Ex: Livereload Chrome)
5.b) Instalas el plugin de tu navegador, en este caso vamos hacerlo con chrome. 
5.c) Reinicia tu navegador 
5.d) En chrome, verás justo arriba a la derecha del navegador un circulo formado por dos flechas representando un ciclo de refresh o recarga con un punto en el centro.

6) Ahora configurar el Plugin del navegador

6.a)En Google chrome esto es tan sencillo como hacer clic derecho encima del icono del livereload, arriba a la derecha y darle a "gestionar extensión o manage extension". 
6.b) Debemos confirmar que esa extensión de chrome está activa, y `DEBES MARCAR las 2 casillas pequeñas de "permitir en incognito" y "todos los accesos a url de archivos".`
6.c) Una vez tengas marcadas las casillas. TODO esta LISTO.

7) Como proceder: 
7.a) PRIMERO ABRIR sublimetext el proyecto.
7.b) SEGUNDO abres tu navegador y vas a tu URL de proyecto Localhost/proyecto/..
7.c) `TERCERO y ULTIMO`, haces `clic IZQUIERDO encima del simbolo del livereload en el navegador`, y verás como el puntito del centro del circulo se colorea y se marca en oscuro.
7.d) Ahora podemos decir que tu navegador está sincronizaado con Sublime Text.
7.e) `Cada vez que GUARDES el proyecto`, puedes usar el comando `Ctrl + S` automaticamente se refrescará y actualizará el navegador.

Espero que te ayude, personalmente creo que es sino uno de los mejores plugin para trabajar con codigo sobre navegador utilizando Sublime Text.
Un saludo!

PD: Tu pregunta es que haciendo un click, o algo puedas ingresar a la URL de la web donde estas, de esta forma consigues practicamente lo mismo cada vez que guardas el proyecto, cosa que hacemos constantemente.

Answer (score 1):

Otro método de poder ejecutar tu PHP es que debes de guardar tu archivo en hdocs, que es una carpeta dentro de Xampp, luego debes de activar el Xampp y poner localhost/nombre que le hayas dado a tu documento.php y se te generara ya sea en el chrome, firefox, o safari.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo una consulta tu quieres que tu pagina en php lo veas atravez del chrome. es facil mi amigo solo en tu archivo buscar la carpeta que has creado .

Siempre debes guardar en la ruta

**C: wamp\www\nombre de la carpeta**

una ves guardado activa tu wamp

Entra a tu chrome y tienes que poner asi

www/localhost/nombre de la carpeta/nombre de la pagina

Comment: Gracias @pierro, eso lo sabía, lo que quiero es que al pulsar por ejemplo F12 desde Sublime se abara dicho archivo en el Chrome.

Comment: Pierro ya lo he solucionado, ese menú estaba en el sidebar lateral y no arriba. Ahí te viene la opción. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @PlayerWet no hay de que mas bien me da gusto que hayas podido resolver tu problema haces un bien a la comunidad :)